# Allow customers to change their details on Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I know that I need code to show where I may have gone wrong, but to be honest I have no idea where to begin.

Shopify is the most ridiculous thing when it comes to features... basic features you would expect just are not there.

So if anyone knows how I can allow customers on Shopify to edit and update their own email and password from within their account I would appreciate it. Or a link to how to do it.

I have looked through the Shopify documentation and Stack Overflow and Shopify forums and Google... I just can't find anything. I have no idea when it comes to things outside of HTML, CSS and basic JS.

I am using Shopify Advanced, not Plus.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Shopify doesn't have a way of allowing the customer to update their information.

It seems like a basic functionality, but it doesn't exist.

In order to achieve this you will need to use an APP such as https://apps.shopify.com/customr

Comment: If they were able to make it, then surely there is a way of doing it ourselves? 
I can't warrant paying the excessive prices of the Shopify apps.

Comment: @Allsops Yes, if you make a custom Application you will be able to make it. But there is no way without an application.

Comment: That's fine by me, do you know of any guide how to set this up?